# Array com HTML e Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário, onde os campos correspondem a quantidade cadastrada no banco de dados. Estou trazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
....
$contar = $metodos->contarCadastro($chave);
$num = 1;
for($c = 1; $c <= $contarPaxes; $c++){
?>
    <div align='left'><label>Nome Completo:</label> <input type='text' name='NomeCompleto[]' id='nome' class='form-control' maxlenght='100'></div>
                <div align='left'><label>E-mail:</label> <input type='text' name='Email[]' id='email' class='form-control' maxlenght='100'></div>
                <div align='left'><label>Data de Nascimento:</label> <input type='text' name='DataNascimento[]' id="date" class='form-control' maxlenght='100'></div>
                <div align='left'><label>CPF:</label> <input type='text' id="cpf" name='CPF[]' class='form-control' maxlenght='100'></div>
<?php } ?>
```

E o jquery:

```
$("#btnCadastrar").on("click", function() {
  var nome = $("#nome").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var data = $("#date").val();
var cpf =  $("#cpf").val();

  $.post("cadastrar.php", {Nome: nome, Email: email, data: data, CPF: cpf }, function() { 
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModa3').modal();
  });
});
});
```

Porém se tiver que cadastrar 03 pessoas, ele só cadastra um. Como faço para que no caso de array, cadastre pelo jquery?

Comment: como está recebendo seu php?

Comment: Com o modo tradicional. mysqli_query($conexão, "INSERT INTO...");

Answer (score 0):

Lembre-se que ID é único por elemento.

Sugestão rápida e fácil:

Crie um `<form>` com um ID qualquer e coloque esses inputs dentro desse `<form>`.

Após isso, em sua função JS faça o seguinte:

```
$("#btnCadastrar").on("click", function() {
    var formElements = $("#idDoSeuForm").serialize();


  $.post("cadastrar.php?"+formElements, function() { 
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModa3').modal();
  });
});
});
```

é claro que você transformar em JSON antes de enviar.